# Divs which expand to fill space yet maintain a minimum width

Tags: css, responsive-design

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="squares">
  <div class="square">text</div>
  <div class="square">text</div>
  <div class="square">text</div>
  <div class="square">text</div>
  <div class="square">text</div>
  <div class="square">text</div>
</div>
```

How do I use CSS to style each `.square` so that its width is at least (for example) 200 pixels, but will expand to be as wide as possible? E.g., if `#squares` is 750 pixels wide, then each `.square` should be 250 pixels wide. If `#squares` is 800 pixels wide, then each `.square` should be 200 pixels wide.

Comment: There is no element query, but there is a media query that you can help do different things based on browser size. Are you saying you want the squares 33% and then 25% like a grid?

Answer (score 0):

But it only work for 750px wide :

```
.square {
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 33.333%;
}

#squares {
   width: 750px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### "Consider the following HTML:"

This HTML is incorrect. There is a closing div above the .squares, and an extra closing div below as well.

### "How do I use CSS to style each .square..."

You have your markup correct. (except for 2 unnecessary closing divs.) Now you take the selector, `.square` and make a rule: The rule is made up of your selector, and 1 or more declaration of property and value.

```
.selector {
    property: value;
}
```

### "so that its width is at least (for example) 200 pixels, but will expand to be as wide as possible?"

```
.square {
    width: 100% /* the full width possible */
    min-width: 200px; /* but at least, 200px */
}
```

### "if #squares is 750 pixels wide, then each .square should be 250 pixels wide."

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
} /* look it up */

#squares {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 750px; /* to keep it squishy */
    float: left; /* because I don't want to clear-fix this - you should though */
}

#squares .square {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 33.333333%; /* a third of the parent to make 250px ? */
    float: left; /* to make a grid */
    border: 1px solid red;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {

    #squares .square {
        max-width: 25%;
    }

}
```

This is a starting point, but I'm not really sure what you want and these styles start to conflict pretty fast. Here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/4hYe5/) you can work with.